# Symfony 4.3 How to enable a Bundle if cloned as git submodule

Tags: symfony-4.3

I want to develop on symfony bundle. So i cloned this in to my project as git submodule add.

But how must i enable this bundle in my Symfony Project, because its not in the vendor, its direct under my project.

So the way to enable this in config/bundle.yaml is not correct i guess? As Example `Bundle\Bundle::class => ['all' => true],`

Because i get the error on bin/console cache:clear

````
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xyz/src/Kernel.php:57
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(424): App\Kernel->registerBundles()
#1 /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(130): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
#2 /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(159): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
#3 /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(65): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands()
#4 /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\ in /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/src/Kernel.php on line 57

Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "XXXPlugin" from namespace "XXX\XXXPlugin".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/src/Kernel.php:57
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(424): App\Kernel->registerBundles()
#1 /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php(130): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeBundles()
#2 /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(159): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot()
#3 /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php(65): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands()
#4 /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\ in /Users/xyz/Webprojekte/xxx/src/Kernel.php on line 57 ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - i found myself the answer. I just need to autoload the bundle in my composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "mybundle\\": "mybundle/src"
    }
```